# SQL Server Service is empty and Server Name can't be found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I used to install SQL Server Management Studio 2014 it was ok, but after I reset my laptop and install it again the SQL Server it doesn't work at all.

1. [It can't not find Server Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Af8w.png)
2. [In SQL Server Configuration -> SQL Server Services are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsPMe.png)

Comment: Well, obviously, there is no SQL Server installed on that machine. You'll need to reinstall.

Comment: OK i'll try!!!!

Comment: You are tagged 2008, 2008r2, 2012 and then writing 2014 in your question.  As marc_s says you might not have SQL server installed. or perhaps you are looking at the wrong tool levels.  For example are you looking at 2012 Configuration manager and you have installed 2014 DBE if so you need to use the 2014 configuration manager.....

Comment: @marc_s i litterally have the same problem, SQL Services are empty, but i have a server installed on that machine, with multiple databases running, and service is visible in services.msc as SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)

Answer (score 7):

This can be because only the SQL Server Management Studio is installed and not SQL Server. Therefore, go to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) or [here to search SQL Server as you require](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/developer-tools.aspx).

Then download and install SQL Express:
32 bits - Download "ENU\x86\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
64 bits - Download "ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"

[Installation Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23878.installing-sql-server-2014-step-by-step-tutorial.aspx)

If the instllation was successful, SQL Services should show results now.

Answer (score 3):

Open the *Services* management console and look for the SQL Server service. The instance name will be displayed next to it. You can then enter `.\<instance name>` (replace `<instance name>` with the correct one) in Management Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the server name field click the down arrow and you will do this steps:

```
 1 - <browse for more...> 
 2 - Click on plus sign next to "database engine" and check if your user name appears
 3 - Click in the name of user -> OK -> Conect.
```